# How to get access to git commit variables (python)?

Tags: python, git, variables, hook, githooks

I am new to git, and am starting to understand how it works.

I am trying to create a personal pre-commit hook to train myself, and I would like to get access to variables such as the username of the committer, number of files committed, their names, titles etc.

How can I do that?

I read this thread https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables and I know some of the variables that interest me exist, but as I said, my problem is not knowing how to access them.

Oh, and I am writing my hooks in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables in that article are all configuration variables that *you* provide to *git*, not variables *git* provides to *you*. Unless you have set them yourself, they will be empty.

`pre-commit` is not provided any arguments.

The name of the committer is obviously the user who is executing the command:

```
import getpass
username = getpass.getuser()
```

To see the files that would be committed (and what action would be taken on each), use `git diff --name-status`:

```
import subprocess
diffs = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'diff', '--name-status'],
                                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
diff_dict = dict(list(reversed(item.split('\t')))
                 for item in diffs.split('\n') if item != '')
```

I don't know what you mean by "titles".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is exactly what I was looking for ! 
Do you know where I could find a list of all the different API and commands that would be useful to me when trying to access git variables? Such as the get pass one in your example... I don't know if I'm clear enough. 

And how would I do a hook that could read in the file that is being committed?

Comment: [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/), [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). If you think that's a lot to read, yes, it is - but your question is that broad (and both sites are useful to read. Actually, probably more "indispensable" than "useful". How you'd read a file - get the filename as above, then read it with Python. (There are many SO answers that tell you how to read a file in Python, given the filename.)

Comment: I think I can manage to do something with these answers ! Thank you :)